# How to add sub menu to Navigation menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I want to completely design a menu, which will look like following screen short
[image: The menu that i want]

The menu that I have designed is in following screenshort

[image: my designed menu]

The HTML code for that menu is given

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>WOMEN</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>MEN</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>JUNIOR</span></a></li>
    <li ><a href='#'><span>ACCESSORIES</span></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><span>COLLECTION</span></a></li>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
              </ul>

    <li><a href='#'><span>SALE</span></a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href='#'><span>MY ACCOUNT</span></a></li>

</ul>
                   </div>
```

Then CSS is given

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 10px black solid;
    height: 49px;


}
#cssmenu ul {
  /*content: ' ';
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;*/

}
#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;


}
#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 9.5px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  border-bottom:10px solid #000 ;

}
.last {
    float:right;
    padding-left:60px;
    font-style:italic;
    }


#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-color:#5ae1e4;
  background-color: #000;
  float:left;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  /*width: 50%;*/
  border-color:#FFF;
}
#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  /*content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;*/
}
#cssmenu ul li a:before {
 /* content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #333333;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;*/
}
#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul li.active a {

}
#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #cssmenu ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:after {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a:before {
    height: 1px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: .2;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li.last > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I can not see the sub collection me. 
Please help me in this.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/tCS2s/ I have posted. pleas see it s looking bad

Comment: Post a working code (like on the screen) please. Also delete the code that is useless as it makes it much harder to read. We are here to help you, not to clean your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1 - Example

Are you looking for something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/tCS2s/7/

---

### 2 - Explanation

Basically what you need to do is make every `.subnev` invisible, by giving this class a `display: none`. You then need to position the submenu elements wherever you need them relative to their triggering link. To do this you need to give the `.subnev` class a `position: absolute` and the parent `li` element a `position: relative`.

After this, you only need to create a trigger. So, in this example, I used the hovering of the link element to trigger the `.subnev`. Triggering, in this case, means changing the `.subnev` `display` attribute from `none` to `block`, in order to make the element visible.

---

### 3 - Code

CSS

```
#cssmenu ul li{
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul li:hover > .subnev{
    display: block;   
}
.subnev{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```